# Intel site says VT-x is supported on my CPU, but tests say otherwise

Tags: virtualbox, cpu, virtualization, vt-x

I have a laptop with an Intel 2nd Gen. i7-2729QM (http://ark.intel.com/products/50067/) and the Intel site says that it supports VT-x, but I've downloaded the Intel Processor Identification Utility (http://www.intel.com/support/processors/tools/piu/sb/CS-014921.htm) and the test says that my CPU does not have VT-x.

There is no option in my BIOS that allows me to enable/disable VT-x. I researched my laptop model (SAGER NP8170) and most forums say that it's enabled by default and there's no option in the BIOS. So assuming that's true, what gives?

I also downloaded another tool called SecurAble from GRC and it also says that my CPU doesn't support VT-x. VirtualBox also says that my CPU does not support virtualization.

My mind is boggled by why it says on the Intel site that my CPU supports VT-x but all other tests show otherwise. Anyone know what's going on? Thanks in advance.

Comment: What does this tool report? http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=592 (VTX is enabled via the BIOS, if you have no option for it then maybe trying flashing to the latest version, or your manufacturer cheaped out and didn't include a way to toggle the feature)

Comment: That tool reports that it only runs on Windows 7, and I have Windows Server 2012. Same result with compatibilty mode for Windows 7. It's very possible that the manufacturer locked it down. I wonder if it's possible to somehow enable it through some sort of hack, if that's the case.

Comment: If the latest bios from the manufacturer doesn't add it, then you'd have to write a custom bios, of which I know nothing :(

Comment: Turns out that Hyper-V was blocking all other virtualization detection attempts because apparently when you enable Hyper-V on a Windows Server 2012 machine, Windows actually runs on top of Hyper-V with some special permissions. Therefore all software in Windows runs on top of that virtualization layer which blocks access to the virtualization layer that Hyper-V leverages (VT-x). Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I realized that Hyper-V was enabled in my system, so I disabled it and everything worked normally. All the aforementioned tools are now reporting VT-x as enabled.